# What is the significance of sql server logical name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

When I restore master db from server A to server B, and run `SELECT @SERVERNAME` on server B, it returns Server A.

This is the logical name of the sql server. I know that it can be corrected using drop/add server.

This question is to ask - what is the significance of sql server logical name? Where is it internally used?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no internal limits about the logical name. It's often being used for all kinds of maintenace scripts and reports that would like to include server's name. Having different hostname and logical name would be confusing, so [changing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) those to match would be a good idea.

An edge case would be granting permissions based on local group membership. Though domain groups should be used, local groups are used now and then, and that might cause issues if logical name won't match hostname.

As for an example,  [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) will complain if `@@servername` doesn't match `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')`. Servername's being used for backup directory structure, so it makes sense to have no mismatches there.

```
  IF @@SERVERNAME <> CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS nvarchar(max)) AND SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') = 1
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Errors ([Message], Severity, [State])
...
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a mismatch would break replication. Perhaps even FCI? AG (I wouldn't think so, but without testing...)